# Style apex select option in Bootstrap theme

Tags: apex, visualforce, bootstrap, selectoption, styleclass

Please help me to style custom picklist in bootstrap theme.

So I have a controller with code:

```
public List<selectOption> getSettings() {
        List<SelectOption> options = new List<selectOption>();
        options.add(new SelectOption('Market/OTC','Market/OTC'));
        options.add(new SelectOption('Margin Lending','Margin Lending'));
        options.add(new SelectOption('Other Services','Other Services'));
        return options;
    }
```

And also the vf page with row:

```
        <div class="form-group">
            <label for="Setting">Setting</label>
            <apex:selectOption value="{!SelectedSetting}" id="Setting" >
                <apex:selectOption value="{!Settings}" />
            </apex:selectOption>
        </div>
```

I want to get something like this:

```
<div class="form-group">
  <label for="Setting">Setting</label>
  <select class="form-control" id="Setting">
    <option>{!Settings}</option>
  </select>
</div>
```

How to do that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can write the bootstrap class in apex selectList.
*Use **styleClass** for write classes of bootstrap*

```
    <div class="form-group">
        <label for="Setting">Setting</label>
        <apex:selectList value="{!SelectedSetting}" id="Setting2" styleClass="form-control" size="1"> <apex:selectOptions value="{!Settings}" /> </apex:selectList>
    </div>
```

Comment: Hi! The styleclass attribute is no longer supported by the apex:selectoption

Comment: I am using this in my code, that is latest

Comment: Ok I get it! the style class attribute is not supported by the selectoption, but the selectlist supports! so the correct answer should look like this: <div class="form-group">
                    <label for="Setting2">Setting</label>
                    <apex:selectList value="{!SelectedSetting}" id="Setting2" styleClass="form-control" size="1">                        
                        <apex:selectOptions value="{!Settings}"  />                        
                    </apex:selectList>
                </div>